# How to correct json in PHP?

Tags: php

On page 1 the form is left by data on the server, and on page 2 return data, but I cannot pick up them, I save in the file, there are data and if I do not save, then I cannot catch them

```
$postdata = file_put_contents('file.txt', json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')
```

and in file `[{"TourDate": "23.01", "Nights": "7", "City": "\u0428\u0430\u0440\u043c-\u044d\u043b\u044c-\u0428\u0435\u0439\u0445", "Hotel": "ALBATROS AQUA BLU RESORT SHARM EL SHEIKH 4+ *", "Board": "AI", "Accomodation": "1 (18+)", "Price": "836", "Month": "01"}]`

i try json_encode, decode, nothing occurred

How to obtain data and to use them?

Comment: "and in file" --- in what file?

Comment: @zerkms probably he means 'file.txt' and he cannot read the JSON data from that file properly?

Comment: You pack three function calls in a single line and don't check the result of any of them. Don't consider your own code as a mysterious black box.

Comment: Assign the `file_get_contents` to a variable and try to print_r it. Do you retrieve the json?

Comment: How in a different way to obtain data?

Comment: It's not clear where your code breaks. Your json is valid but we can't tell if you fail to put it in the file or you fail to retrieve it from the file. This is something you must tell us.

Comment: what about the file_get_contents. Do you retrieve the data first of all? Does it work?

Comment: I place in the file only to trace whether data came, they come. But I cannot take them in any way

Comment: "But I cannot take them in any way" --- show your best attempt. At this moment you don't even try to access anything from that JSON structure.

Comment: Your JSON is fully valid, the problem is your understanding of data and how it is delivered via POST I guess. You also don't seem to understand the difference between encode and decode. You can easily read the data from the file with `json_decode(file_get_contents('file.txt'));`.

Comment: New code: `<?php

$postdata = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
file_put_contents('file.txt', (string) file_get_contents('php://input') , FILE_APPEND);

var_dump($postdata);
?>` in file write [{"TourDate": "23.01", "Nights": "7", "City": "\u0428\u0430\u0440\u043c-\u044d\u043b\u044c-\u0428\u0435\u0439\u0445", "Hotel": "ALBATROS AQUA BLU RESORT SHARM EL SHEIKH 4+ *", "Board": "AI", "Accomodation": "1 (18+)", "Price": "836", "Month": "01"}] in frontend display array(0) { }

Answer (score -3):

```
$postdata = file_put_contents('file.txt', json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input');

$tour = json_decode_custom(file_get_contents('file.txt'));

$tour->TourDate; // 23.01
$tour->Nights; // 7
...

function json_decode_custom($json)
{
    return json_decode(trim($json, "[]"));
}
```

Comment: -1 from me: not only this is the code-only answer, but it also promotes the worst possible practice of manipulating serialised data (via string functions). You at least should explain what your code is supposed to fix the problem (which is unclear from the question).

Comment: It does not make sense to manipulate valid json into other (still valid) json using string functions. Very bad advise. I agree to consider answers without explanation bad quality on SO and not helpful in most cases.

Comment: @DanFromGermany this is  an array manipulation: $tour[0]->TourDate to $tour->TourDate